# Trying to get svn2git working on Windows

Tags: ruby, git, svn, git-svn

I'm migrating an SVN repository over to Git. The git-svn command doesn't handle the branches and tags properly but I stumbled across a tool called svn2git which seems to resolve this (https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git).

I've tried setting up this tool to work on Windows but I've not had much success.

I started off by copying the svn2git installation to C:\svn2git and downloading Ruby for Windows (http://rubyinstaller.org/) and saved it at C:\Ruby193.

Running svn2git came back with

```
/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

I then copied Ruby's bin and lib folders to svn2git's bin and lib folders respectively.

Running the svn2git then came back with

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError) from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

Does anyone know how to get this working on Windows environment? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with git-svn and your branches? Do you have non-standard trunk/branches/tags layout?

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko: the problem is that tags aren't created as real git tags but as branches instead. svn2git converts svn tags to git tags. This has nothing to do with a special repo layout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Obviously, `rubygems.rb` is missing. Install it as documented here:
https://rubygems.org/pages/download

Then, install `svn2git` as instructed here:
https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

After that, everything shall be fine.

Comment: The `rubygems.rb` install link is broken.

Comment: @JoeSkeen: thanks for the notification; updated links.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest you to try [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) tool. It does translate Subversion tags as tags and works well on Windows (requires Java 5 or newer). SubGit is ready to use. You may get latest build at [download page](http://www.subgit.com/download.html) and read documentation on the [web site](http://subgit.com/).

Originally in 2012 early SubGit versions required local access to Subversion repository (over file system) but later on (by 2015) on network access to subversion was added.

Disclaimer: I'm SubGit developer.

Comment: thanks for the mention! You should edit this since it now works over network to access the repo. I just used subgit + am much happier than using `git svn clone` (much faster) and although I have not tried svn2git I am suspicious in that it is a ruby-driven use of the git-svn tool, hence probably slow for large repos.

Comment: Dude is gone, if facts are outdated, just edit as I have done here.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to migrate from SVN is the trunk and it's commit history, you can easily do it with the following git commands:

```
git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=http://[svnHostName]/svn/[projectTrunkUrl] --no-minimize-url
git svn fetch --log-window-size=4000
```

Tadahhh! You have initialized your local git repository with all your SVN trunk repository history!

Now you probably want to add a default remote and push:

> https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-remote
>
> https://help.github.com/en/articles/pushing-to-a-remote