# Clone SVN Repo to Git (with all revisions) Using TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, clone, tortoisegit

I am brand new to Git, and I make making the leap from SVN. Is it possible to clone all of the revisions and files (basically the whole repo) from SVN to Git using TortoiseGit? If so, could someone instruct me as to now I can do this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in this [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion) page, **[svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git)** remains the recommended solution to import an SVN repo into a git one.
And *then* you can use TortoiseGit.

Svn2Git is for one shot, [or one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402117/how-can-one-integrate-svn-and-git) conversion from SVN to Git, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013966/how-to-use-svn-dcommit-for-svn-all-fast-export-qt-script). It can [work on Windows too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717571/trying-to-get-svn2git-working-on-windows).

Comment: Unfortunate that the svn2git process on Windows is such a pain.